# How to drop remove unwanted index headers in Pandas multilevel data frame

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'value': [10,10,12,13,14,15],
               'gene_symbol': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
               'cellprep': ['xxx', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'xxx', 'zzz'],
               'measure': ['tpm','tpm','tpm','fpkm','fpkm','fpkm']})


ndf = df.pivot_table(index=['cellprep','gene_symbol'], columns='measure').fillna(0)
ndf.reset_index(drop=True,level=1)
```

Which produces the following data frame:

```
         value
measure   fpkm   tpm
cellprep
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx       14.0   0.0
yyy        0.0  12.0
zzz       13.0   0.0
zzz       15.0   0.0
```

What I want to do is to write that data frame into a TSV file 
that looks simply like this

```
cellprep   fpkm   tpm
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx       14.0   0.0
yyy        0.0  12.0
zzz       13.0   0.0
zzz       15.0   0.0
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add parameter `values` to [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
ndf = df.pivot_table(index=['cellprep','gene_symbol'], 
                     columns='measure', 
                     values='value').fillna(0)

print (ndf.reset_index(drop=True,level=1))

measure   fpkm   tpm
cellprep            
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx       14.0   0.0
yyy        0.0  12.0
zzz       13.0   0.0
zzz       15.0   0.0
```

Another solution is [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
ndf = df.pivot_table(index=['cellprep','gene_symbol'], columns='measure').fillna(0)
ndf.columns = ndf.columns.droplevel(0)
print (ndf.reset_index(drop=True,level=1))
measure   fpkm   tpm
cellprep            
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx        0.0  10.0
xxx       14.0   0.0
yyy        0.0  12.0
zzz       13.0   0.0
zzz       15.0   0.0
```